# How to override .properties files in firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I know that one can override `.xul`, `.xhtml` and `.css` files using the `override` keyword in the `chrome.manifest` file of an extension.

Now I'm trying to override a `.properties` file the same way, but it does not seem to work.

My line is:

```
override chrome://devtools/locale/debugger.properties chrome://myextension/content/debugger.properties
```

The chrome url of the `.properties` file is take from the source code, so it should be correct. The `content` directory is correctly imported, because other overrides work fine.

Is there another way, or are `.properties` files not supported?

Comment: Interesting question, I'm not sure how to do this, eager to see the solution though.